# JSON response prints index number

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have this array,

```
$sql = "SELECT s.sitter_id,s.sitter_id,s.name as sitter_name,s.mobile_no FROM `maggie_trusted_circle` t INNER JOIN maggie_sitters s ON t.sitter_id = s.sitter_id Where t.mom_id =". $params['mom_id'];
        $trusted_circle = $this->db->executeQuery($sql);
```

and i am using this to acess more data via

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($trusted_circle); $i++)
        {

              $mutual_friend = $trusted_circle[$i]['sitter_id'];
              $mutual_friend_name = $trusted_circle[$i]['sitter_name'];
              $sql = "SELECT s.sitter_id,s.name as sitter_name,s.mobile_no FROM `maggie_trusted_circle` t INNER JOIN maggie_sitters s ON t.sitter_id = s.sitter_id Where t.mom_id =". $mutual_friend;
              $extended_trusted_circle[$i] = $this->db->executeQuery($sql);
              $extended_trusted_circle[$i]['mutual_friend_id']= $mutual_friend;
              $extended_trusted_circle[$i]['mutual_friend_name']= $mutual_friend_name;


        }
```

and encoding the response

```
 return json_encode(array('flag'=>1, 'message'=>'Success' ,'extended_trusted_circle'=>$extended_trusted_circle);
```

everything works fine, except the index numbers are also printed in the JSON Response

[image]

what could be the reason for this? i believe normally the index numbers are not printed along, am i missing something?

Comment: json_encode translates php arrays (that are indexed by integers) to hashes, and it used the indexes (converted to strings) as keys

Comment: BTW if you would show us the json output you want to achieve we might easier help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see those 0-s is that:

```
$extended_trusted_circle[$i] = $this->db->executeQuery($sql);
```

return an array like:

```
array(0 => array('sitter_id'=>44,...))
```

0 is the row number, but it always returns only 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Try to die(); after json_encode